# How do I resume the iTunes queue from when I last quit?

Tags: itunes

iTunes 11 appears to be saving my queue from when I last quit it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>—all unplayed songs remain in the queue, listed under "Up Next".  However, I cannot determine a way to resume this queue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start iTunes and verify your queue is empty and you are on the Albums view.
2. Double-click an album to add it.
3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> to exit.
4. Restart iTunes.

If I press Play at this point, the queue appears to fill with my entire library and start with the first album shown.

How can I resume my queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me *and is much quicker if you're like me and prefer keyboard shortcuts*:

Open iTunes and…

1. Press <kbd>►►</kbd> (F9).
2. Press <kbd>►II</kbd> (F8).

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  A variation: if I instead hit rewind before play, I can restart the song that was playing when I quit iTunes.

Comment: This also works when the queue icon is inaccessible (for example if an iPhone is syncing)

Answer (score 2):

A queue left-over from an iTunes exit, as above, can be resumed thus:

1. Click the queue icon.
2. Double-click the first song in the queue.

[image]