# How Do I Resume an Up Next Playlist?

Tags: itunes, music, playlist

Okay, so I use iTunes for both music and video (movies and TV shows), however, when switching between the two I can't figure out how to resume the music that was remaining in my Up Next queue.

I can open the queue and see the items, but how do I actually resume playing from it (and once the queue is empty, whichever playlist was selected to follow it)?

I've never been able to get iTunes to reliably let me do this, as it usually just asks if I'm sure I want to clear the queue, regardless of how I try to resume; this even happens if I had no queued items at all (just a playlist set to shuffle) and hit play or shuffle from the same playlist.

To give an example use case:

1. Select a music playlist and hit the shuffle button to start some music playing.
2. Add some music to Up Next via the Play Next and/or Add to Up Next options (via right-click or plus button in search).
3. Switch to the Movies or TV Shows tab and start watching something.
4. Return to the Music tab.

At this point, how do you resume your Up Next queue without clearing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click the icon in the upper right of the area that showcases the songs and then double click the first song in the list.

See [How do I resume the iTunes queue from when I last quit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95493/how-do-i-resume-the-itunes-queue-from-when-i-last-quit)

[image]

In the case of this picture, I must double click on "Pilotwings 'Liftoff (Get High)'"